# openFoam: Trouble reporting turbulence fields

Tags: openfoam

I run openFoam 4.1, and have a problem extracting the turbulent stress tensor, R, in my k-eps simulation. I asked the same question on cfd-online.com 4 days ago, and have not received a reply, so I am now hoping that maybe someone can help me here.

To extract R, I have only modified the controlDict, which looks like the following:

```
/*--------------------------------*- C++ -*----------------------------------*\
| =========                 |                                                 |
| \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox           |
|  \\    /   O peration     | Version:  4.0                                   |
|   \\  /    A nd           | Web:      www.OpenFOAM.org                      |
|    \\/     M anipulation  |                                                 |
\*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
FoamFile
{
    version     2.0;
    format      ascii;
    class       dictionary;
    object      controlDict;
}
// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

application     simpleFoam;

startTime       0;

stopAt          endTime;

endTime         5000;

deltaT          1;

writeControl    timeStep;

writeInterval   100;

purgeWrite      2;

writeFormat     ascii;

writePrecision  8;

writeCompression uncompressed;

timeFormat      general;

timePrecision   6;

runTimeModifiable yes;

functions
{
#includeFunc    residuals

    turbulenceFields1
    {
        type            turbulenceFields;
        libs            ("libfieldFunctionObjects.so");
        field           R;
    }
}

// ************************************************************************* //
```

When I try solving with the above controlDict, I get the following:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
| =========                 |                                                 |
| \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox           |
|  \\    /   O peration     | Version:  4.1                                   |
|   \\  /    A nd           | Web:      www.OpenFOAM.org                      |
|    \\/     M anipulation  |                                                 |
\*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
Build  : 4.1
Exec   : simpleFoam
Date   : May 18 2017
Time   : 07:08:01
Host   : "..."
PID    : 11073
Case   : /home...
nProcs : 1
sigFpe : Enabling floating point exception trapping (FOAM_SIGFPE).
fileModificationChecking : Monitoring run-time modified files using timeStampMaster
allowSystemOperations : Allowing user-supplied system call operations

// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //
Create time

Create mesh for time = 0


SIMPLE: convergence criteria
    field p     tolerance 0.001
    field U     tolerance 0.001
    field "(k|epsilon|omega|f|v2)"     tolerance 0.001

Reading field p

Reading field U

Reading/calculating face flux field phi

Selecting incompressible transport model Newtonian
Selecting turbulence model type RAS
Selecting RAS turbulence model kEpsilon
kEpsilonCoeffs
{
    Cmu             0.09;
    C1              1.44;
    C2              1.92;
    C3              -0.33;
    sigmak          1;
    sigmaEps        1.3;
}

No MRF models present

No finite volume options present


Starting time loop

turbulenceFields turbulenceFields1: storing fields:
    turbulenceProperties:R

Time = 1

smoothSolver:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 1, Final residual = 0.068919891, No Iterations 6
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 1, Final residual = 0.094423261, No Iterations 4
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 1, Final residual = 0.065365879, No Iterations 6
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 1, Final residual = 0.0086113464, No Iterations 26
time step continuity errors : sum local = 0.51812432, global = -0.07783965, cumulative = -0.07783965
smoothSolver:  Solving for epsilon, Initial residual = 0.59675441, Final residual = 0.051409907, No Iterations 3
smoothSolver:  Solving for k, Initial residual = 1, Final residual = 0.092548244, No Iterations 2
ExecutionTime = 0.81 s  ClockTime = 1 s



--> FOAM FATAL ERROR: 
object of type N4Foam9Function1INS_10SymmTensorIdEEEE is not allocated

    From function T* Foam::autoPtr<T>::operator->() [with T = Foam::Function1<Foam::SymmTensor<double> >]
    in file /home/ubuntu/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-4.1/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/autoPtrI.H at line 176.

FOAM aborting

#0  Foam::error::printStack(Foam::Ostream&) at ??:?
#1  Foam::error::abort() at ??:?
#2  Foam::timeVaryingMappedFixedValueFvPatchField<Foam::SymmTensor<double> >::write(Foam::Ostream&) const at ??:?
#3  Foam::GeometricField<Foam::SymmTensor<double>, Foam::fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh>::Boundary::writeEntry(Foam::word const&, Foam::Ostream&) const at ??:?
#4  Foam::GeometricField<Foam::SymmTensor<double>, Foam::fvPatchField, Foam::volMesh>::writeData(Foam::Ostream&) const at ??:?
#5  Foam::regIOobject::writeObject(Foam::IOstream::streamFormat, Foam::IOstream::versionNumber, Foam::IOstream::compressionType) const at ??:?
#6  Foam::functionObjects::regionFunctionObject::writeObject(Foam::word const&) at ??:?
#7  Foam::functionObjects::turbulenceFields::write() at ??:?
#8  Foam::functionObjectList::execute() at ??:?
#9  Foam::Time::loop() at ??:?
#10  Foam::simpleControl::loop() at ??:?
#11  ? at ??:?
#12  __libc_start_main in "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6"
#13  ? at ??:?
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It seems from the above like openFoam solves for the first time step, and then something goes wrong. In the the catalog "1" there is now only one file, "turbulenceProperties:R", which seams to contain the 6 elements of the stress tensor for each point.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer, in the [this](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-post-processing/153322-error-using-r-utility.html#post632575) link from the cfd-online forum.